# Parse list of JSON URLs through fromjson

Tags: r, json, rjsonio

I have a table of urls that each point to a certain json output. I would like to parse them through `fromJSON` (or any other json parser), in order to extract data from these json outputs, and combine it together in a list of lists.

My code is set up as follows:

```
pages <- list()
for (i in 1:length(urltable))
{
mydata<-fromJSON(urltable[i], flatten=TRUE)
pages[[i]] <- mydata$entries
}
```

which renders the errorterm:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) :
unable to find inherited method for function 'fromJSON' for signature '"list", "missing"'
```

If i test it with pasting a single url in `fromJSON()`, it works, so i suppose the problem lies in the fact that `fromJSON` does not read the table?

Anyone having a suggestion of how to do this?

Addition: The urltable is a table of 1 column, and 326 rows. the head of the table is:

```
    url
1     http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aalzum&start=10
2     http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aalzum&start=20
3 http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=10
4 http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=20
5 http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=30
6 http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=40
```

Addition 2 subset of urltable, `dput(subset_urltable)`:

```
structure(list(url = c("http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aalzum&start=10","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aalzum&start=20","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=10","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=20","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=30","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=40","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=50","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=60","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=70","http://zoeken.kvk.nl/Jsonsearch.ashx?site=handelsregister&partialfields=&q=Aardenburg&start=80")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = "url")
```

Comment: can you also post your data?

Comment: @DhawalKapil sure, not much data. It is a table of 1 column, and x rows of only urls. Please see the original post for the addition. Thanks for helping out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromJSON` expects a json string, in your case you are trying to retrieve json data and convert it in a single go. You will have to feed data from your url to `fromJSON`. Do something like this

```
mydata<-fromJSON(url(urltable[i]), flatten=TRUE)
```

`url` will feed extracted data to `fromJSON` function.

Complete solution should look like

```
pages <- list()
for (i in 1:length(urltable))
{
mydata<-fromJSON(url(as.character(urltable[i])), flatten=TRUE)
pages[[i]] <- mydata$entries
}
```

with `curl` package installed you can do without explicitly using `url` function.
Also, if you want to iterate over all rows of `urltable` do not use `length(urltable)` as it will return the no of columns in your data frame which is 1 here, instead do `length(urltable$url)`

```
pages <- list()
for (i in 1:length(urltable$url))
{
    mydata<-fromJSON(as.character(urltable$url[i]), flatten=TRUE)
    pages[[i]] <- mydata$entries
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, if I try that, I get the following error: Error in url(urltablel[i]) : invalid 'description' argument.

Comment: check if `nieuw_url[i]` is a string element, if not do `as.character(nieuw_url[i])`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. nieuw_url = the same as urltable. But, if I do as.character(nieuw_url[i]), then i get the following error: URL Scheme unsuported by this method....

Comment: can you take a subset of your data, do a `dput(smalldata)` and paste the exact output in your question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170131/discussion-between-dhawal-kapil-and-roberthaa).